# How to Copy Org-Mode Contents Under a Heading

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, org-mode

In org-mode I need to quickly copy content under a heading to the kill ring excluding the heading itself. I found the function `org-copy-subtree`, but it copies the entire subtree with the heading.

In the following example I would like to copy "Sample text line 1" and "Sample text line 2" when my cursor is somewhere in the "My Sample Heading 1":

```
* My Sample Heading 1
Sample text line 1
Sample text line 2
* My Sample Heading 2
Sample text line 3
Sample text line 4
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's just text, so you could mark the region and do `M-w`.

Answer (score 3):

This *might* be a bit of a dead question, but here's my solution in case anyone happens upon this and wants to use the `org-mark-subtree` way of doing it:

```lisp
(defun my/org-copy-text-under-heading ()
  (interactive)
;; Select the current Org subtree
  (org-mark-subtree)
;; Deselect the heading line
  (next-line 1)
;; Copy the current region
  (kill-ring-save
   (region-beginning)
   (region-end))
;; Deselect the region after copying
  (deactivate-mark))
```

I've just tried to explain that answer a little more fully (as I assume the `jy` will only work with Evil Mode?).

Answer (score 1):

This will return a substring of everything under the current headline. If you want to kill the contents directly, just replace `buffer-substring-no-properties` with `kill-region`.

```
(save-excursion
 (org-back-to-heading)
 (forward-line)
 (unless (= (point) (point-max))
  (let ((b (point))
        (e (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max))))
   (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `org-mark-subtree` then `jy`.

Comment: Can you expand your answer with a) some contextual code (similar to the previous answer) and an explanation of what this does and why it solves the problem? That will be a more useful answer.

Comment: I like the solution. After M-x org-mark-subtree, I can move the cursor down to skip the heading itself.

The thing I was trying to do, was to clone a week's work and prepare for a new week, but some contents should be moved over, some (mostly) should be archived, while keeping the headings structure.